# How to create a list of n copy of x?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create simple procedure that would copy an element n-times into resulting list.

What I've done so far is:

```
cp(1, X, [X]).
cp(N, X, D):- N > 0, N1 is N - 1, append(X, D,D1), cp(N1,X,D1).
```

Comment: Read the documentation for `append/3`. You're not using it correctly. Also, `cp(1, X, Y)` will succeed twice with your rules. That's not a good thing in this case. You probably want `N > 1` in your second clause.

Comment: And here's a fun solution to figure out: `cp(N, X, L) :- length(L, N), maplist('='(X), L).` You can even query `cp(N, X, L)` with all variables and it gives reasonable solutions.

Comment: @lurker: No need for `'` just `=(X)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution to the task

```
cp(1, X, [X]).
cp(N, X, D):- N > 1, N1 is N - 1, cp(N1,X,D1), append(D1, [X], D).
```

Comment: As was said in the original comments, and again by Tomas, you do not need `append/3`. Just write, `D = [X|D1]`. And you can just write: `cp(N, X, [D|D1]) :- N > 1, N1 is N - 1, cp(N1, X, D1).`